# Android Location getTime to hours

Tags: android, gps, location, gettime

I have a location object to which I'm assigning the result of the `getLastKnownLocation()` method.

Now I need to know the age of these coordinates, in order to set a reasonable time frame in which I can update the latitude and longitude. I'm using `Location.getTime()` to get this value. However, I'm confused as to how exactly I should go about converting this value into hour. I need to update the location coordinates every X hours, hence the reason I need the value of `getTime()` in hours.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried with Calendar but gives the wrong date. Below code is working fine.

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
return sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the [UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You can turn it into a date with `Date date = new Date(location.getTime())`.

You can also use [Android's Calendar class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html):

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(location.getTime());
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to extract the hour from the timestamp, convert to Date and add X hours:

```
Date d = new Date(location.getTime());

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(d);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, X);
```

Then get the time for the update with:

```
calendar.getTime();
```